# Is there a way to transition the transform:scale property using only css?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am using

```
transform: scaleY(0.8);
```

in a :hover event.  Is there a way to make this transition over time?  The only way I know to transition things is to do

```
-webkit-transition: someparm sometime somefunction;
-moz-transition: someparm sometime somefunction;
-o-transition: someparm sometime somefunction;
transition: someparm sometime somefunction;
```

But I can't figure out how I would do it with a transform.

Comment: You should be able to do it with @keyframes and an animation.

Comment: Do you mean `transform` with `transition` like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/47qav0mv/) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
```

or

```
transition-property: transform;
transition-duration: 0.4s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
transition-delay: 0s;
```

So something like this

```
a {
  transform:scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
a:hover {
    transform:scale(0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes scale {
    100% { transform:scaleY(0.8);}
    }

/* on hover */

abc:hover{
-webkit-animation:scale 3s ease infinite;
}
```

**try to animate it **